# How to add VLC-Android as a module/library to my current android project?

Tags: android, kotlin, vlc, vlc-android

Vlc-Android source code link: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android#project-structure

my requirement is to add this library as a module/library in order to use it to play video. When i try to import the root folder as module i get different errors.

any idea what I'm doing wrong?